# Est-ce que « de son vivant » se dit?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Exemple:

> Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait de son vivant.

D’autres variantes qui ont la même signification que l’idée que je cherche à formuler.

> Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait quand cela lui était encore possible.

> Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait durant sa vie.

> Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait quand il lui était encore possible de le faire.

——————————————————

Autre tournure qui me vient à l’esprit:

> Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait le temps qu’il le pouvait encore.

Même chose pour cette phrase rimante que je viens de concevoir et qui n’a - je vous l’assure - aucun rapport avec la réalité:

> Il aurait dû la battre à mort le temps qu’il le pouvait encore.

Clarification:

Joël [il], qui est mort, aurait dû dire  de son vivant et de vive voix à sa femme, Elsa, qu’il l’aimait.

N’hésitez pas à me proposer d’autres variantes d’un autre style et de meilleure langue.

Comment: En vie, il ne l'a pas fait, lui dire qu'il l'aimait !

Comment: Ses cendres, ont-elles des remords de ne lui avoir dit « Je t'aime » ?

Comment: Effectivement Personne!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui, la locution adverbiale « du vivant de quelqu'un, de son vivant » se dit pour « pendant la vie de quelqu'un » ([Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/vivant), [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vivant/82299#184407), [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vivant), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_son_vivant)) ; en son vivant serait *vieilli* (TLFi) :

> Elle travaillait à diminuer ses imperfections (...) à s'instruire. **Du
> vivant** de mon père, tout cela se soumettait, se fondait dans un grand
> amour (Gide, *Si le grain*, 1924, p. 463, au TLFi).
>
> Poiresson et Périnet, fils l'un et l'autre de défunt Jean de Vouthon,
> frère d'Isabelle Romée, **en son vivant** couvreur de son état (A. France,
> *J. d'Arc*, t. 2, 1908, p. 452, au TLFi)

J'aime bien ça et c'est donc la tournure que je préfère. Je la verrais aussi très bien après *dire* :

> Il aurait dû lui dire [de son vivant] à quel point il l’aimait [de son
> vivant].

Comment: La phrase a-t-elle le sens attendu selon la clarification ou bien une reformulation serait de rigueur? LPH prétend même qu’il y a une incongruité dans la phrase.

Comment: @GermaineLeBrun Il y a le contexte et pour moi une phrase n'a pas à tout énoncer pour être valide et claire, il ne s'agit pas de mathématiques où l'absence d'un terme serait possiblement fatale. Si les interlocuteurs sont au courant de la situation, on comprend _du vivant du défûnt_, pendant qu'il était en vie, et _dire à son épouse_ ; le sujet est « il », c'est incontestablement Joël. Évidemment qu'une personne décédée ne peut s'exprimer, on est en train de dire essentiellement « quand il en avait la chance, alors qu'il le pouvait ». Quant à cette inconguité, que de chimères à mon avis.

Answer (score 0):

> **1** Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait de son vivant.

Il y a à mon avis une incongruité irréparable dans cette phrase : si on peut dire quelque chose à quelqu'un c'est forcément tant que cette personne est en vie ; cela revient un peu à dire « Il aurait dû vivre (prendre du plaisir, etc.) pendant qu'il vivait. ». En conséquence je ne l'utiliserais pas. Il reste à savoir s'il y a derrière cette phrase une idée qui se tient, et ça c'est une question beaucoup plus difficile. Je suppose que ce qui motive cette phrase c'est un regret, ce qui serait la possibilité la plus évidente.

- Maintenant qu'il était mort il regrettait de ne jamais lui avoir dit à quel point il l'aimait.

> **2** D’autres variantes qui ont la même signification que l’idée que je cherche à formuler.
>
> - Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait quand cela lui était encore possible.

La présente possibilité pallie l'inconvénient, à mon avis criant, de la première phrase, mais n'est pas sans laisser à l'esprit une idée de cas évident. Il est vrai que c'est une phrase que l'on pourrait qualifier de phrase type, qui se dit facilement, que l'on semble trouver quelques fois. Oui, bien sûr, le seul moment pendant lequel cela pouvait être considéré c'était quand il y avait la possibilité de le faire.

> **3**  Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait durant sa vie.

J'associe cette nouvelle phrase à la première puisque « durant sa vie » et « de son vivant » sont des expressions synonymes.

> **4** Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait quand il lui était encore possible de le faire.

Le problème de la phrase « 2 » se retrouve dans cette phrase n° 4, qui est essentiellement la même.

> **5** Autre tournure qui me vient à l’esprit:
>
> • Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait le temps qu’il le pouvait encore.

Cette dernière phrase est du type des phrases « 2 » et « 4 », et on peut en dire la même chose qui a été dite pour ces dernières.

> Même chose pour cette phrase rimante que je viens de concevoir et qui n’a - je vous l’assure - aucun rapport avec la réalité:
>
> • Il aurait dû la battre à mort le temps qu’il le pouvait encore.

En ce qui concerne cette dernière phrase je ne trouve rien d'autre à dire que ce que j'exprime déjà dans le commentaire à propos de la « 2 ».

En conclusion, considérant que l'auteur puisse tenir à l'idée d'opportunité manquée que communique le conditionnel « il aurais dû », je pense que la phrase suivante est une autre option.

• Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait ; maintenant qu'il était mort, d'avoir négligé de montrer son affection le laissait triste/le tourmentait un peu/le torturait/lui inspirait un léger dégout ineffable de lui-même/le faisait se sentir  égoïste/l'emplissait de regrets amers/…. (*Dans la version précédente « le torturait »  n'est qu'un exemple.*)

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

## Après clarification dans le PO

> **1** Il (Joël, mort) aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait (sa femme) de son vivant (du vivant de Joël).

La même incongruité reste manifeste, cela mis à part qu'elle me semble encore plus apparente ;  si on peut dire quelque chose à quelqu'un c'est forcément tant qu'on est en vie ; le problème consiste à trouver quelle idée a été remplacée inexactement par « de son vivant » ; il me semble que c'est une caractérisation de la fréquence d'une action sur la durée totale d'une vie.

- Il aurais dû lui dire à quel point il l'aimait, ce qu'il n'a jamais fait.
- Il est mort sans jamais lui avoir dit à quel point il l'aimait, ce qu'il aurait dû faire.
- Jusqu'à sa mort il ne lui aura pas dit une seule fois à quel point il l'aimait, et c'est pourtant ce qu'il aurait dû faire.

> **2** D’autres variantes qui ont la même signification que l’idée que je cherche à formuler.
>
> - Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait quand cela lui était encore possible.

La présente possibilité pallie l'inconvénient, à mon avis aberrant, de la première phrase, mais n'est pas sans laisser à l'esprit une idée de cas évident. Il est vrai que c'est une phrase que l'on pourrait qualifier de phrase type, qui se dit facilement, dont il semble qu'on  trouve des exemples du même modèle quelques fois. Oui, bien sûr, le seul moment pendant lequel cela pouvait être considéré c'était quand il y avait la possibilité de le faire.

> **3**  Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait durant sa vie.

J'associe cette nouvelle phrase à la première puisque « durant sa vie » et « de son vivant » sont des expressions synonymes.

> **4** Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait quand il lui était encore possible de le faire.

Le problème de la phrase « 2 » se retrouve dans cette phrase n° 4, qui est essentiellement la même.

> **5** Autre tournure qui me vient à l’esprit:
>
> • Il aurait dû lui dire à quel point il l’aimait le temps qu’il le pouvait encore.

Cette dernière phrase est du type des phrases « 2 » et « 4 », et on peut en dire la même chose qui a été dite pour ces dernières.

> Même chose pour cette phrase rimante que je viens de concevoir et qui n’a - je vous l’assure - aucun rapport avec la réalité:
>
> • Il aurait dû la battre à mort le temps qu’il le pouvait encore.

En ce qui concerne cette dernière phrase je ne trouve rien d'autre à dire que ce que j'exprime déjà dans le commentaire à propos de la « 2 ».

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141504/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-est-ce-que-de-son-vivant-se-dit).

Comment: @LPH Voir Clarification svp.

Comment: @GermaineLeBrun Je vais essayer de vérifier encore si cela change quelque chose.